# IOS-TableView Cell: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

---

In my project, I create everything by code, like tableviews and cells. I have function to add cells.
The situation is: I have 10 object in my array, when program runs, the function `(- (TodoTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath)` runs through all 10 cells as I scroll, it does run 10 times of init... function in cell class. BUT, when I add a new cell in the program, then I found that this new cell never calls the init function for some reason. (The cell is being successfully created though... weird)

I use this part to add cell:

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.todoItemList insertObject:newItem atIndex:toBeAddedIndex];
    [self.tableView insertSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:toBeAddedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and in this function:

```
- (TodoTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"Scroll to %ld", indexPath.section);
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TodoCell";

TodoTableViewCell *cell = (TodoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//If the current cell is dummycell, make it transparent
cell.todoItem = (TodoItem *)(self.todoItemList[indexPath.section]);
```

I don't know why, anyone please kindly help

----------UPDATE-----------------

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TodoCell%ld",indexPath.section];
```

I found that if I change to this line. every time a add a new cell, it just calls the init function! but... if I do delete first and then add, problem still there, because this identifier has been created and used and stored I guess.

Answer (score 1):

try to call:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>]
```

Comment: problem is that I use section instead of rows, because I need gap between cells. so that the function: heightForHeaderInSection is quite helpful for me.

Comment: I tried:                                                   [self.tableView insertSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:toBeAddedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                               [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:toBeAddedIndex]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];                              the init function of new created cell still not getting called.

Comment: Which init are you calling?
I think you should call - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am calling. the first 10 times of this function is being called. but no more! since I add any more cells by insert section function. (It does show the new cell though)